# CXF Servlet API method to list all service beans?

Tags: java, spring, cxf

I'm trying to get metadata about the service beans that are managed by CXF in the current context.

Due to WADL auto-generation limitations (I don't want to create a message body reader for each type we add) I don't want to use that. I can manually parse the cxf servlet xml file but would much rather avoid doing so.

Is there some way through the API I can get a list of the service beans in the current context?

I've tried searching for hours and can't find it. The servlet is using Spring, by the way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've just needed to do something similar. After a lot of playing around I was able to come up with this:

```
    final Bus bus = CXFBusFactory.getDefaultBus();
    final ServerRegistry serverRegistry = bus.getExtension(ServerRegistry.class);
    final List<Server> servers = serverRegistry.getServers();
    return servers.stream().map(s -> s.getEndpoint().getService())
            .filter(s -> JAXRSServiceImpl.class.isAssignableFrom(s.getClass())).map(JAXRSServiceImpl.class::cast)
            .map(JAXRSServiceImpl::getClassResourceInfos).flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .map(ClassResourceInfo::getResourceClass).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

It looks up all of service classes (not the instances, unfortunatly) but for my use case (and posably yours also, the class was sufficient)